# ¿Cómo consigo obtener el número de registros BD y pasarlos a un Jlabel?

Tags: java, java-swing, sqlite

No consigo pasar de este punto, y es que tengo que recoger el número de registros en la base de datos SQLite y mostrarlos en una JLabel. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Éste es mi código:

```
public final class Tarea extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Connection conexion = null;

    private PreparedStatement ps = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form Tarea
     */
    public Tarea() {
        initComponents();

    }

    private void muestraRegistro() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        int contador = 0;

        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conexion =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:pacientes.sqlite");
            ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM datos");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                contador++;
               etiRegistro.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
            }
            rs.beforeFirst();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tarea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
```

---

Modificando el código como me habéis comentado:

```
private void muestraRegistro() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:pacientes.sqlite");
        ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM datos;");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            etiRegistro.setText(rs.getString("total"));
        }
        rs.beforeFirst();
        conexion.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tarea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Sigue sin mostrarme el número en el JLabel.

Comment: te saludo y te comento por lo que veo trabajas con Java por lo cual la etiqueta de Javascript no es necesaria ya que son cosas distintas, te recomiendo quitar dicha etiqueta

Comment: Pero quieres directamente el número de registros o que vaya aumentando con cada iteración del bucle? Si quieres directamente el número total, cambia el SQL a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM datos`

Comment: Quiero el numero de registros directamente. Estoy perdido

Answer (score 1):

Yo cambiaría la consulta por:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM datos;`

De esta forma obtienes el número de registros que hay en la tabla datos.

Y luego lo pasas a tu JLabel:

```
    ps = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM datos;");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
       etiRegistro.setText(rs.getString("total");
    }
    rs.beforeFirst();
    conexion.close();
```

Comment: voy a probarlo ;)

Comment: sigue sin mostrar el numero de registros en el jlabel

Comment: ¿@Alberto estás refrescando el panel?